# Java Web Start Eclipse from Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, java-web-start, jnlp

I created a Java GUI Application: it's ok!
Now I want to create a JNLP from my project with Eclipse: is it possible? How?
I try the "Java Web Start Plugin" but I can't install it (Eclipse say "don't find the jar file").

Any suggestion?

Comment: how are you installing the webstart plugin?  you can try this location http://webstart.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the WS4E.zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/webstart/

Extract it and go to WS4E/plugins and copy the net.sourceforge.webstart_1.2.1 folder in your eclipse/plugins installation directory and restart eclipse.

Comment: Does this work with Luna release? I'm doing exactly that and it doesn't show up.

Comment: For me neither (Luna).